# how to encode data using nested ifelse() in R

Tags: r

I am facing a problem in nested ifelse() statement in R. I have a dataframe which has a column Age. I have to encode the data by following condition-

1. If Age <=18, then Age=child
2. If Age >18 and <=60, then Age=adult
3. If Age >60, then Age=senior.

I used following code to solve the problem

```
ifelse((Titanic$Age <= 18),Titanic$Age <-'child',ifelse((Titanic$Age>18 & Titanic$Age<=60),Titanic$Age <- 'adult',Titanic$Age <- 'senior'))
```

The problem I am facing is that it turns all rows in age column 'senior' even through most values range around 20-40

Comment: `ifelse` returns the value to be assigned; don't use `<-` inside `ifelse`. `Titanic$Binned_age <- ifelse(Titanic$Age <= 18, 'child', ifelse(Titanic$Age <= 60, 'adult', 'senior')))`. Or better yet, use `cut` as in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Better to keep the original data and add a category colum next to the ages
One direct answer with no package is as follow:

```
Titanic$categeory <- with(Titanic, ifelse(Age<18,yes = "child2",no = ifelse(Age<=60,yes = "Adult",no = "Senior")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case_when` from `dplyr`. It allows to vectorize multiple `if_else` statements:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(111)
df <- data.frame(Age = runif(100, 0, 90))

df <- df %>% mutate(Age = case_when(Age <= 18 ~ "child 2",
                                    Age > 18 & Age <= 60 ~ "adult 3",
                                    TRUE ~ "senior"))
```

If you need `Age` to be a factor variable, convert it:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(Age = as.factor(Age))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have numeric values you can use cut and then rename the levels.
This uses only base functions.

```
# some dummy data
dummy <- data.frame(age = runif(100, 0,100))

# actual code: 
# cut the data based on the thresholds. Look into the documentation to see whether the sets borders are included to the left or the right.
dummy$agebracket <- cut(dummy$age, breaks = c(0,18,60,9999))
# now we just rename them to our liking
levels(dummy$agebracket) <- c("child 1", "child 2", "senior")
```

As a comment to your code: The bug is that you overwrite the whole vector with lines like this

```
Titanic$Age <- 'senior'
```

You'd want to do something closer to this

```
Titanic$agebracket <- 
ifelse((Titanic$Age <= 18), 'child',
  ifelse((Titanic$Age>18 & Titanic$Age<=60),'adult', 'senior'))
```

But I would try to stay away from these nested ifs if you can. 
They are hard to read and might not work in more complex situations.

Answer (score 0):

To explain why your code doesn't work: when you do

```
ifelse(
    Titanic$Age <= 18, 
    Titanic$Age <-'child', 
    ifelse(...) 
)
```

if it goes in the `if` part of `ifelse` it will assign`child` to all rows because  you are executing the statement `Titanic$Age <-'child'`. In your example it goes in the last `ifelse` and assigns `senior` to all rows.

What you want instead is

```
ifelse(
    Titanic$Age <= 18, 
    'child', 
    ifelse(...)
)
```

But after a few nested `ifelse` statements this becomes very hard to read so I recommend `case_when` from `dplyr` like @slava-kohut showed in his answer.